# data isn't being inserted into my SQL table but it's also saying there's duplicate primary keys

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

So I'm just trying to have registered users data show up in an SQL table. I know that I have successfully connected to the database but none of the data is being added. I am not sure why this is. When I do run the code it I get an SQLException about a duplicate entry 'username' for primary key. here's the code

```
public void createUser() throws SQLException{

    String query = " INSERT INTO users(username, password, name, email)"
            + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement statement = db.getConn().prepareStatement(query);
    statement.setString(1, String.valueOf(username));
    statement.setString(2, String.valueOf(password));
    statement.setString(3, String.valueOf(name));
    statement.setString(4, String.valueOf(email));

        statement.executeUpdate();
      //  error is here
        statement.close();
        db.getConn().commit();
        System.out.println("success");

}
```

I'm able to print out all the username/password/name/email stuff no problem. The error is being thrown up on the `statement.executeUpdate()` line.

here's the database being created.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`username`))
COMMENT = "this is a test table";
```

I can insert data on MySQLWorkbench no problem and I can do `DESCRIBE users` and see the table with the users manually created in the workbench but I'm not sure why the java method isn't working. thanks for your time!

edit: changed from `statement.setString(1, "username");` to `statement.setString(1, String.valueOf(username));` and so on. but am now getting a data truncation error. `Data truncation: Data too long for column 'username' at row 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you are inserting fixed values into the statement rather than your intended values.

```
statement.setString(1, "username");
    statement.setString(2, "password");
    statement.setString(3, "name");
    statement.setString(4, "email");
```

You shouldn't have quotes around the variable names. E,g:

```
statement.setString(1, username);
    statement.setString(2, password);
    statement.setString(3, name);
    statement.setString(4, email);
```

Comment: thanks for taking a look. I just changed it to        `statement.setString(1, String.valueOf(username));`   and so on for the others but I am now getting data truncation error. `Data truncation: Data too long for column 'username' at row 1`    is what it says

Comment: @user10871827 If the variables are already Strings you won't need to use valueOf(). You'll need to do this with all of the values you are trying to insert into the statement though, at the moment you would be inserting "username, password, name, email" each time the query is performed.

Comment: @user10871827 Just saw your edit, is the username less than 45 characters?

Comment: I just figured it out. I needed to do `statement.setString(1, username.getText());` since it was being grabbed from a textfield. So the idea is users are registering on this page and they will be inserting that data to complete the process. I mostly just wrote it that way to establish and test the inserting process. I'll probably try and look into a for loop or something for setting my prepared statement cause I imagine it can be done more efficiently. do you have any ideas off the top of your head? thanks for the help!

Comment: Np, I'd suggest setting variables like `String username = username.getText();` or even using getters and setters. This will make it easier to work with as I'd recommend doing validation on the data being passed from the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

check table `user`,if there is `username` value of '1',drop it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

That's because username is your primary key and you are trying to insert duplicate records into table for username column.
Check if the username you are trhing to insert, is already there in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try few things to debug it further.

1) Try passing string values in statement.setString() method, to confirm your db call is in place.

public void createUser() throws SQLException{

```
String query = " INSERT INTO users(username, password, name, email)"
        + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement statement = db.getConn().prepareStatement(query);
statement.setString(1, "Test");
statement.setString(2, "Test");
statement.setString(3, "name");
statement.setString(4, "abc@abc.com");

    statement.executeUpdate();
  //  error is here
    statement.close();
    db.getConn().commit();
    System.out.println("success");
```

}

2) Try to print values for username before you call statement.setString(), and check

3) Check the existing data in table , perhaps you are trying to key in duplicate record. cause username is primary key for your table.